# If $x$ is rational, can $\log(1-x)/\log x$ be algebraic?

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, exponential-function

If $x$ is positive rational number less than $\frac{1}{2}$,  can the following logarithmic expression be equivalent to real algebraic number, say $g$?

$$\frac{\log(1-x)}{\log x} = g$$

Comment: Hint: $\frac{\log(1-x)}{\log x}=g\Rightarrow \log(1-x)=\log x^g\Rightarrow 1-x=x^g$

Answer (score 13):

Your identity gives:
$$ 1-x = x^g \tag{1}$$
where $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ trivially gives that the LHS is a rational number. If $g$ is not a rational number, the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) gives that the RHS is a trascendental number, contradiction.

So $g$ has to be a rational number. But in order that $1-x$ and $x^g$ are rational numbers with the same denominator, $g$ has to be one. So $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $g=1$ is the only solution.

Comment: Actually the question was excluding (x=1/2 or x= 0), therefore, no solution for the alleged question or equation unless (g) is transcendental number?

Comment: @bassamkarzeddin: yes, exactly.

Comment: Which proves FLT in short!!

Comment: I don't believe this proves FLT...