# Prove on sin equality over integers

Tags: number-theory

I would need to prove there exist at least a $k > 1, k \in \mathbb{N}$ such as the expression:

$\sin( \phi_1 +\frac{2\pi m}{\log{k}}) =  \sin( \phi_1 +\frac{2\pi m'}{\log{(k+1)}})$

has not solution where $m, m' \in \mathbb{Z}$

I have tried to manipulate this expression, and come with equivalent one as it can be seen on this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593472/prove-expression-involving-log-has-no-solution-on-mathbbz): However the solution provided to that expression requires the unproven Schanuel's conjecture.

Any other hint on this reshaped expression?

My attempt:

$\phi_1 +\frac{2\pi m}{\log{k}} =  \phi_1 +\frac{2\pi m'}{\log{(k+1)}} + 2\pi t$

$\frac{m}{\log{k}} =  \frac{m' +t\log(k+1)}{\log{(k+1)}} $

$ {m}{\log{(k+1)}} =  {m'}{\log{k}}+ t\log(k+1)\log{k}$

$ \log((k+1)^m) =  \log(k^{m'})+ \log((k+1)^t)\log{k}$

$ e^{\log((k+1)^m)} =  e^{\log(k^{m'})}e^{\log((k+1)^t)\log{k}}$

$ (k+1)^m =  k^{m'} ((k+1)^t)^{\log{k}}$

Comment: Of course disregarding the case when $m=0$.

Comment: Note that

$$\sin a = \sin b\implies a=b+2k\pi \quad\lor \quad a=\pi-b$$

Comment: Thanks for the note. I don't know if I am missing anything, but somehow that is what I tried to cover with the $ + 2\pi t$. Could you please point what am I missing ?

Comment: It not seems a simple problem to me, maybe it can be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311922/if-x-is-rational-can-log1-x-log-x-be-algebraic